# JPA not save with DB

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, apache-tomee

everyone!

I use spring+jpa. Run it all on the TomEE server. In the tomee file i have correct datasource to my MySQL server. When I execute persist operation of the entityManager I receive this log

```
2015-05-01 01:57:46,740 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] 

implementations.CommonDaoImpl (CommonDaoImpl.java:42) - save method ended success
2015-05-01 02:22:09,697 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] implementations.CommonDaoImpl (CommonDaoImpl.java:32) - getById method started with id=1
[EL Finer]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.698--ServerSession(160948815)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--client acquired: 1920349854
[EL Finer]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.698--ClientSession(1920349854)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--acquire unit of work: 788265415
[EL Finest]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.698--UnitOfWork(788265415)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--Execute query ReadObjectQuery(name="readUser" referenceClass=User sql="SELECT LOGIN, FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME, PASSWORD, SECONDNAME FROM USER WHERE (LOGIN = ?)")
[EL Finest]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.698--ServerSession(160948815)--Connection(550211562)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
[EL Finest]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.698--ServerSession(160948815)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--reconnecting to external connection pool
[EL Fine]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.699--ServerSession(160948815)--Connection(341138552)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--SELECT LOGIN, FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME, PASSWORD, SECONDNAME FROM USER WHERE (LOGIN = ?)
    bind => [1]
[EL Finest]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.703--ServerSession(160948815)--Connection(550211562)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [read].
[EL Finer]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.703--UnitOfWork(788265415)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--release unit of work
[EL Finer]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.703--ClientSession(1920349854)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--client released
2015-05-01 02:22:09,703 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] implementations.CommonDaoImpl (CommonDaoImpl.java:34) - getById method ended with obj=null
2015-05-01 02:22:09,712 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] implementations.UserServiceImpl (UserServiceImpl.java:47) - saveNotActivatedUser method started with user = 1[1, null, 1][STUDENT, STUDENT]
2015-05-01 02:22:09,713 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] implementations.CommonDaoImpl (CommonDaoImpl.java:40) - save method started with entity=1[1, null, 1][STUDENT, STUDENT]
[EL Finer]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.714--ServerSession(160948815)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--client acquired: 1983904739
[EL Finer]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.714--ClientSession(1983904739)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--acquire unit of work: 1655845051
[EL Finest]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.714--UnitOfWork(1655845051)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--persist() operation called on: 1[1, null, 1][STUDENT, STUDENT].
[EL Finer]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.716--UnitOfWork(1655845051)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--release unit of work
[EL Finer]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.716--ClientSession(1983904739)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--client released
2015-05-01 02:22:09,716 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] implementations.CommonDaoImpl (CommonDaoImpl.java:42) - save method ended success
2015-05-01 02:22:09,716 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] implementations.UserServiceImpl (UserServiceImpl.java:49) - saveNotActivatedUser method ended successfull
2015-05-01 02:22:09,717 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] implementations.CommonDaoImpl (CommonDaoImpl.java:40) - save method started with entity=entity.Activation@209d779c
[EL Finer]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.717--ServerSession(160948815)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--client acquired: 1108849534
[EL Finer]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.717--ClientSession(1108849534)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--acquire unit of work: 571029272
[EL Finest]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.718--UnitOfWork(571029272)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--persist() operation called on: entity.Activation@209d779c.
[EL Finer]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.722--UnitOfWork(571029272)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--release unit of work
[EL Finer]: 2015-05-01 02:22:09.723--ClientSession(1108849534)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--client released
2015-05-01 02:22:09,723 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-2] implementations.CommonDaoImpl (CommonDaoImpl.java:42) - save method ended success
```

Look like all is correct. But in the my data base is no one data row.

Here my persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="joyUnit">
        <class>entity.User</class>
        <class>entity.Activation</class>
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>JoyDS</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"></property>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"></property>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
            <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="true"></property>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Or can someone tell me how executes the binding jta-data-sources in the java. Because I don't understand all about JTA transaction type. 
And what this code find in spring?

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="joyUnit" />
    </bean>
```

I think that tomee connect to the inside db but in the log I saw

```
[EL Config]: 2015-05-01 01:57:46.33--ServerSession(160948815)--Connection(692349912)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>DatabasePlatform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>null
))
[EL Config]: 2015-05-01 01:57:46.331--ServerSession(160948815)--Connection(2016054357)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:mysql://localhost/joy
    User: user@localhost
    Database: MySQL  Version: 5.6.20
    Driver: MySQL Connector Java  Version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.31 ( Revision: alexander.soklakov@oracle.com-20140520065950-groqzzbvxprqdmnz )
[EL Finest]: 2015-05-01 01:57:46.332--ServerSession(160948815)--Connection(828595733)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
[EL Finest]: 2015-05-01 01:57:46.332--ServerSession(160948815)--Connection(828595733)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [read].
[EL Config]: 2015-05-01 01:57:46.332--ServerSession(160948815)--Connection(1924517383)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>MySQLPlatform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>null
))
[EL Config]: 2015-05-01 01:57:46.338--ServerSession(160948815)--Connection(37511204)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main])--Connected: jdbc:mysql://localhost/joy
    User: user@localhost
    Database: MySQL  Version: 5.6.20
    Driver: MySQL Connector Java  Version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.31 ( Revision: alexander.soklakov@oracle.com-20140520065950-groqzzbvxprqdmnz )
```

Could someone explain why db login sets 3 times???

Because some time ago I could write to DB correct without persistence.xml file in classpath, but have in tomee datasource with name 'joyUnit'

Comment: `Entitymanager.persist` operation does not write an entity to the underlying database, it only adds an entity to the persistence context. Did you commit the changes after persisting them?

Comment: Yes - You are right. I try add entityManger.flush() - it's tell me that I execute all out of transaction.

Comment: But why? If I use JTA, than container controls when open and commit the transactions. But it seems - it's not. Does anyone know why?